# Add more then one site logo - custom-logo theme support

Tags: customization, theme-development, theme-customizer, logo, header-image

We can add one site logo to site customize with  `add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );`

How can add another logo? Seems like the [custom-logo theme support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo) only allows to add one site logo and I need to a footer logo as well

I know its possible to add this to a custom theme settings page but prefer to add this to the customize screen same place where theme logo is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
    'height' => 480,
    'width'  => 720,
) );
```

You could also go with:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'height' => 480,
    'width'  => 720,
) );
```

Use the custom-header for the top logo and the custom-logo for the footer (or the other way round).

Another approach might be to [define a thumbnail size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/):

```
 add_image_size( 'custom-footer-logo', 220, 220, array( 'left', 'top' ) );
```

You would have to work with [the WordPress customizer controls](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/) to make a control to add and change the footer. But you could add as many images to your theme as you want that way.

Comment: My question is how to add more than one. did you try to add more than one?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I will edit my answer.

Comment: this can work, add_theme_support( 'custom-logo'). the issue is how can I add text to allow the user know this is the footer logo and not header logo it appears as just "logo"

Comment: I've not explored the area in question but I am pretty sure there are hooks for changing the customizer.